# How to 'wait' for two observables in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

In my app i have something like:

```
this._personService.getName(id)
      .concat(this._documentService.getDocument())
      .subscribe((response) => {
                  console.log(response)
                  this.showForm()
       });

 //Output: 
 // [getnameResult]
 // [getDocumentResult]

 // I want:
 // [getnameResult][getDocumentResult]
```

Then i get two separated results, first of the `_personService` and then the `_documentService`. How can I wait for both results before call `this.showForm()` to finish an then manipulate the results of each one.

Comment: forkJoin https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: for what I understand, you already are, by virtue of `concat`

Comment: @user3743222 In this case, the values are being emitting separately. One after other.

Comment: in forkJoin' subscribe will get one result - tuple  with first and second responses - this is what exactly that you asked?

Comment: you can look at forkJoin in my blog post - https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d

Comment: @ggui They are right, use `forkJoin`.

Comment: forkjoin does not always work as it requires both observables to "complete". at times you want to both have fired "next" but not necessarily "completed"

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### ***Last Update: Mar, 2022.***

### RxJS v7: combineLatestWith

From reactiveX [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith):

> Whenever any input Observable emits a value, it computes a formula using the latest values from all the inputs, then emits the output of that formula.

```
// Observables to combine
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();
    
name$.pipe(
        combineLatestWith($document)
      )
      .subscribe(([name, document]) => {
           this.name = name;
           this.document = pair.document;
           this.showForm();
       })
```

### (Deprecated) RxJS v6 combineLatest()

From reactiveX [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-combineLatest):

> Whenever any input Observable emits a value, it computes a formula using the latest values from all the inputs, then emits the output of that formula.

***(Update: Feb, 2021)***:

```
// Deprecated (RxJS v6)
// Observables to combine
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();
    
name$.combineLatest(document$, (name, document) => {name, document})
    .subscribe(pair => {
           this.name = pair.name;
           this.document = pair.document;
           this.showForm();
       })
```

***(alternate syntax)***: combineLatest(observables)

```
// Deprecated (RxJS v6)
// Observables to combine
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();
    
combineLatest(name$, document$, (name, document) => ({name, document}))
    .subscribe(pair => {
           this.name = pair.name;
           this.document = pair.document;
           this.showForm();
       })
```

---

## zip vs combineLatest

***(Update: Oct, 2018)***
I previously suggested the use of `zip` method. However, for some use cases, `combineLatest` has a few advantages over `zip`. So it is important to understand the differences.

`CombineLatest` emits the latest emitted values from observables. While `zip` method emits the emitted items in ***sequence*** order.

For example if observable #1 emits its **3rd** item and observable #2 has emitted its **5th** item. The result using `zip` method will be the **3rd** emitted values of both `observables`.

In this situation the result using `combineLatest` will be the **5th** and **3rd**. which feels more natural.

---

## Observable.zip(observables)

***(Original answer: Jul, 2017)*** Observable.zip method is explained in [reactiveX documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-zip):

> Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are calculated from the values, in order, of each of its input Observables.

```
// Observables to combine
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();
    
Observable
    .zip(name$, document$, (name: string, document: string) => ({name, document}))
    .subscribe(pair => {
           this.name = pair.name;
           this.document = pair.document;
           this.showForm();
       })
```

---

### a side note (applies for both methods)

The last parameter, where we have provided a function, `(name: string, document: string) => ({name, document})` is optional. You can skip it, or do more complex operations:

> If the latest parameter is a function, this function is used to compute the created value from the input values. Otherwise, an array of the input values is returned.

So if you skip the last part, you get an array:

```
// Observables to combine
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();
    
Observable
    .zip(name$, document$)
    .subscribe(pair => {
           this.name = pair['0'];
           this.document = pair['1'];
           this.showForm();
       })
```

Comment: Is it possible to wait for completion of one observable with this ?, my observable have another inner observable, which in turn rely on an http.get ?

Comment: In your Jan 2020 update, why map the array to object? Seems like an unnecessary step when you could destruct the array within the subscribe method. That would be my only comment, the rest looks good.

Comment: OOOOHHHH, I was looking for combineLatest operator for an hour... many thanks

Comment: How do you unsubscribe from the combined observables ? Just unsubscribe from the observable that is returned from combinedLatest().subscribe() ?

Comment: `combineLatest` has been deprecated in favour of `combineLatestWith`, see here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatest

Answer (score 69):

Use `forkJoin()` method of observables. [Check this link for reference](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

From the RXJS [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been receieved for all. In this way it is similar to how you might use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our character
  // results[1] is our character homeworld
  results[0].homeworld = results[1];
  this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
});
```

Code taken from: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: Is it possible to wait for completion of one observable with this ?, my observable have another inner observable, which in turn rely on an http.get ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI If you wanna do sth. after completion of one observable, can you use nesting subscription?

Comment: @YuweiHE very bad advice, for that there is switchmap/flatmap operators. avoid nested subscription

Answer (score 33):

The [RxJS Operators for Dummies: forkJoin, zip, combineLatest, withLatestFrom](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/rxjs-operators-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom) helped me a lot. As the name states it describes the following combination operators:

- [ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin)
- [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip)
- [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)
- [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom)

Any of them could be the thing you are looking for, depends on the case. Check the article for more info.

Comment: Thanks the first link you have given i.e "RxJs Operators ..." is a must read and the best and easiest explanation you can ever get

Answer (score 10):

Improvement of [Hamid Asghari answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44936594/860099) which use direct arguments decomposition and automatically add types (when you use typescript)

```js
const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();

combineLatest([name$, document$]).subscribe(([name, document]) => {
    this.name = name;
    this.document = document;
    this.showForm();
});
```

**BONUS**: You can also handle errors using above approach as follows

```js
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
//...

const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();

combineLatest([
  name$.pipe(     catchError( () => of(null as string  ) ) ), 
  document$.pipe( catchError( () => of(null as Document) ) ), // 'Document' is arbitrary type
]).subscribe(([name, document]) => {
    this.name = name;          // or null if error
    this.document = document;  // or null if error
    this.showForm();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**June 2021**

With rxjs 6.6.7

Use *combineLatest* like this otherwise is deprecated

```
combineLatest([a$ , b$]).pipe(
      map(([a, b]) => ({a, b})) //change to [a , b] if you want an array
    )
```

Also see @nyxz post

> **zip** - the love birds, always work as a team, triggers only when all
> observables return new values
>
> **combineLatest** - the go dutch, start trigger once all observables
> return new values, then wait for no man, trigger every time when
> either observable return new value.
>
> **withLatestFrom** - the master slave, master first waits for slave, after
> that, action get triggered every time only when master return new
> value.
>
> **forkJoin** - the final destination, trigger once when all observables
> have completed.

From : https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom/amp

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the 'combineLatest' method, it might be appropriate here.
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest

```
const { Observable } = Rx

const name$ = this._personService.getName(id);
const document$ = this._documentService.getDocument();

Observable
    .combineLatest(name$, document$, (name, document) => ({ name, document }))
    .first() // or not, implementation detail
    .subscribe(({ name, document }) => {
        // here we have both name and document
        this.showForm()
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this [sample](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#sample) was best solution.

```
const source = Observable.interval(500);
const example = source.sample(Observable.interval(2000));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log('sample', val));
```

So.. only when second (example) emit - you will see last emited value of first (source).

In my task, I wait form validation and other DOM event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'zip' or 'buffer' like the following.

```
function getName() {
    return Observable.of('some name').delay(100);
}

function getDocument() {
    return Observable.of('some document').delay(200);
}

// CASE1 : concurrent requests
Observable.zip(getName(), getDocument(), (name, document) => {
    return `${name}-${document}`;
})
    .subscribe(value => console.log(`concurrent: ${value}`));

// CASE2 : sequential requests
getName().concat(getDocument())
    .bufferCount(2)
    .map(values => `${values[0]}-${values[1]}`)
    .subscribe(value => console.log(`sequential: ${value}`));
```