# Angular 6 ng lint combineLatest is deprecated

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, tslint

I recently updated from Angular 5 to Angular 6.

I'm getting this warning `combineLatest is deprecated: resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead`. Rxjs is version 6.1.0, tslint is 5.10.0, Angular CLI is 6.0.0 and Typescript 2.7.2. I'm using it like this:

```js
const a$ = combineLatest(
  this.aStore.select(b.getAuth),
  this.cStore.select(b.getUrl),
  (auth, url) => ({auth, url}),
);
```

I've tried it also like this:

```js
empty().pipe(
combineLatest(...),
  ...
)
```

But this gives me: `combineLatest is deprecated: Deprecated in favor of static combineLatest` and empty is also deprecated in favor of its static version.

Comment: you can also try a$.pipe(a$ => combineLatest(a$,b$, c$)); with import { combineLatest } **from 'rxjs'**;

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> *combineLatest is deprecated: resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead*

The above warning is recommending to remove the resultSelector the last function you provided in combineLatest observable and provide it as part of map operator as follows

```js
const a$ = combineLatest(
  this.aStore.select(b.getAuth),
  this.cStore.select(b.getUrl)
);

const result$ = a$.pipe(
  map(results => ({auth: results[0], url: results[1]}))
)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you see *`combineLatest is deprecated: Pass arguments in a single array instead`* then just add []:

```js
const a$ = combineLatest([
  this.aStore.select(b.getAuth),
  this.cStore.select(b.getUrl)
]);
    
const result$ = a$.pipe(
  map(results => ({auth: results[0], url: results[1]}))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but combineLatest will make an array so I have to do it like this:
`const result$ = a$.pipe(map((a) => ({auth: a['0'], url: a['1']})));`

Comment: Personal preference, but I much prefer a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) here to mapping to a new object. So like: `const result$ = a$.pipe(tap(([auth, url]) => { /* ... */ }));`

Comment: What if I wanted to use a projector function like in the old `combineLatest()`, how would I go about this?

Comment: Update https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792658/5466477

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately you might also get that tslint error if you import combineLatest from operators:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
combineLatest(...array);
```

instead of,

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
    
combineLatest(...array);
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike the deprecated versions, `combineLatest` accepts an **Array** of `Observable` and returns an array containing the latest values from each. Every stream has to yield in order for `combineLatest` to yield.

```
fruitType$ = combineLatest([this.entity$, this.datasetStateService.get$('Fruits')])
  .pipe(map(data => {
    const entity = data[0];
    const dataset = data[1];
    return {
       isApple: (dataset.find(ds => ds.label === 'Apple') as DataItem).id === entity.fruitId,
       isOrange: (dataset.find(ds => ds.label === 'Orange') as DataItem).id === entity.fruitId
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it's because I explicitly set generic argument, so an incorrect `combineLatest` overload was selected. To get rid of the warning I've changed

```js
combineLatest<void>([
    firstObservable$,
    secondObservable$
]);
```

to

```js
combineLatest([
    firstObservable$,
    secondObservable$
]).pipe(
    mapTo(undefined)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `trailing comma` error, remove the comma after `(auth, url) => ({auth, url})`

```
const a$ = combineLatest(
  this.aStore.select(b.getAuth),
  this.cStore.select(b.getUrl),
  (auth, url) => ({auth, url}),  // Remove this comma.
);
```

For `missing import` error, Make sure you have imports for all the external var's or classes you are using in the file.

Example, in this case, if you havent imported `combineLatest`, then import it

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; // For RxJS 6.x

import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators'; // For RxJS 5.x
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I wasn't being clear. Those were not actual issues but I was just giving an example to the problem how the issues were being reported twice. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

i used depricated combineLatest to combine those two observables this.route.paramMap +  this.route.queryParamMap:

```
combineLatest(this.route.paramMap, this.route.queryParamMap)
  .subscribe(combined => {
    const idFollower = combined[0].get('id');
    const page = combined[1].get('page');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve that this way:

```
auth$ = this.aStore.select(b.getAuth);
url$ = this.cStore.select(b.getUrl);

combinedResult$ = combineLatest([this.auth$, this.url$]).pipe(
    map(([auth, url]) => ({auth, url}))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by passing in an array of `Subscription` items, instead of actual observables, lol. (I got really sloppy on this one.)

***WRONG!***

```js
const foo = Foo$.subscribe(f => {
  // do something with f here
})

const bar = Bar$.subscribe(b => {
  // do something with b here
})

combineLatest([foo, bar]).subscribe(([f, b]) => {
  // do something after both foo$ and bar$ have emitted something
})
```

***CORRECT!***

```js
const foo$ = Foo$.pipe(
  tap(f => {
    // do something with f here
  })
)

const bar$ = Bar$.pipe(
  tap(b => {
    // do something with b here
  })
)

combineLatest([foo$, bar$]).subscribe(([f, b]) => {
  // do something after both Foo$ and Bar$ have emitted something
})
```