# combineLatest deprecated in favor of static combineLatest

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

After running the rxjs migration tool using

> rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json

I'm now getting a linting error:

> combineLatest is deprecated: Deprecated in favor of static
>   combineLatest.

Here is my code before running the migration command:

```
this.store.combineLatest(
        this.store.select(lang.getCurrent),
        this.store.select(lang.getCurrentLocale)
    ).subscribe(([state, currentLang, locale]) => {
        this._language = session.language === currentLang ? '' : currentLang;
        this._locale = session.locale === locale ? '' : locale;
    });
```

My code after running the migration command: (currently presenting a linting error)

```
import {map, combineLatest} from 'rxjs/operators';
this.store.combineLatest(
        this.store.select(lang.getCurrent),
        this.store.select(lang.getCurrentLocale)
    ).subscribe(([state, currentLang, locale]) => {
        this._language = session.language === currentLang ? '' : currentLang;
        this._locale = session.locale === locale ? '' : locale;
    });
```

The question was asked in this stackoverflow questions, but it was  not specific enough: [Angular 6 ng lint duplicate errors and warnings, combineLatest is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274275/angular-6-ng-lint-duplicate-errors-and-warnings-combinelatest-is-deprecated)
.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

### Deprecated!

Please refer to [ofir fridman's answer for the correct syntaxs as of RxJs 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56208571/6042764)

---

I found an answer in this article titled: [RxJS 6: What's new and what has changed?](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/) ( which comes from [official docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#dep-methods)):

The solution is to convert:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';

a$.pipe(combineLatest(b$, c$));
```

into:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest([a$, b$, c$]);
```

Comment: or if you want to preserve combineLatest inside your pipe, you can do `a$.pipe(a$ => combineLatest(a$,b$, c$));`

Comment: It would appear that this solution is now deprecated too. What's the new new way?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let us know if ofir fridman's answer is out of date.

Comment: I am using rxjs version 6.5.3 and idea ultimate 2020.1.2. and import combineLatest from "rxjs" instead of "rxjs/operators" as suggested in the rxjs official docs but it is still marked as deprecated by intellij. It is f**ing annoying!

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble. It sounds like your local TSLint version is a mismatch! Good luck.

Comment: @ParrapbanzZ the version that accepts multiple observables is indeed deprecated. You should pass in an array of observables instead. E.g., `combineLatest(a$, b$)` instead of `combineLatest([a$, b$])`

Answer (score 141):

## In rxjs 6.5+

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest([a$, b$, c$]);
```

And for most applications it's helpful to map the array of observables to a new value as well:

```js
combineLatest([a$, b$, c$]).pipe(
  map(([a$, b$, c$]) => ({
    a: a$, 
    b: b$, 
    c: c$
  }))
);
```

Also see: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: This creates an Observable<[typeof(a), typeof(b), typeof(c)]> instead of single combined type

Comment: Why would you map and return an object, when it already is an array of the streams?

Answer (score 5):

rxjs version 6.4.0

You should import map operator from RxJs operators for it to work

```js
combineLatest(a$, b$, c$).pipe(map([a, b, c]) => treat(a, b, c))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the most complete answer here, however.

All the other answers return a different type of observable than the expected type, which requires this handling to be applied.

It says the least but offers the most.

Answer (score 5):

Seems `combineLatest` has been deprecated and passing an array as suggested in the various answers still throws the error in rxjs v.7.0.0 [Deprecation Notice](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatest#deprecation-notes)

> Replaced with [`combineLatestWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith). Will be removed in v8.

For those using rxjs v.7.0.0 and above you will need to use `combineLatestwith`

```js
input1Changes$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(input2Changes$)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest([
  this.store.select(lang.getCurrent),
  this.store.select(lang.getCurrentLocale)
]).subscribe(([state, currentLang, locale]) => {
    this._language = session.language === currentLang ? '' : currentLang;
    this._locale = session.locale === locale ? '' : locale;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

combineLatest with a list of subscribers:

```
combineLatest([aSubscriber, bSubscriber]).pipe(map((aRes, bRes)=>{
// your business logic
}));
```