# Join 2 observable streams, but have distinct accessors

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'd like, very much like in ngrx's selector definition, where you're able to plug a number of observables and have a projection function to return something.

Example

```
export const selectCommunityByRouteId = createSelector(
  selectRouteId,
  communitySelectors.selectEntities,
  (id, communities) => {
    if (id) {
      return communities.find(c => c.id === id);
    }
  }
);
```

^There is a `selectRouteId` and `communitySelectors.selectEntities`, 2 observable streams and a projection function that takes both inputs and returns something.

The below code is in my component. Essentially what I'm doing is determining if the owner of a community is the same that is visiting this community and if it is, set the admin only menu items to be seen.

Current

```
    this.community$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngDestroyed$),
      switchMap(community => this.store.select(selectProfileByID(community && community.owner_id))),
    ).subscribe(profile => {
      if (profile) {
        const claims = this.oAuthService.getIdentityClaims();
        if (claims) {
          // @ts-ignore
          const sub = claims.sub;
          if (sub === profile.subject_id) {
            this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({items: [
                {title: 'New Forum', route: ['/new/forum']}
              ]}));
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({items: undefined}));
      }
    });
  }
```

However now I'm 2 levels deeper in the nest and in a `Community` > `Container` > `Forum` relationship, I'm trying to give the owner the possibility to create a new forum. For this however I need to know the id of the `Container` I'm currently viewing. I have a

```
    this.container$ = this.store.select(selectContainerByRouteId);
```

this is not the issue.
This issue is, I need to access the information coming from this selector/observable.
So, in my subscribe I need to have not just

```
this.store.select(selectProfileByID(community && community.owner_id)
```

but also

```
this.container$
// or
this.store.select(selectContainerByRouteId)
```

so I have something like

```
.subscribe([profile, container] => {
// do something with that
});
```

or, more elaborate

Desired:

```
    this.community$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngDestroyed$),
      switchMap(community => this.store.select(selectProfileByID(community && community.owner_id))),
    ).subscribe([profile, container] => {
      if (profile) {
        const CONTAINER_ID_HERE = container.id;
        const claims = this.oAuthService.getIdentityClaims();
        if (claims) {
          // @ts-ignore
          const sub = claims.sub;
          if (sub === profile.subject_id) {
            this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({items: [
                {title: 'New Forum', route: ['/new/forum', CONTAINER_ID_HERE]}
              ]}));
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({items: undefined}));
      }
    });
  }
```

I know there's forkJoin, but this just combines all streams into a single one.

What I'm looking for is a way to take data from multiple streams and pass it to the next function. I believe [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) should do it.

What would the function have to look like with combineLatest? Could I still use switchMap? Can I even pass it in a pipe?

Comment: You managed to answer your own question at the same moment you posted it, that's impressive.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to throw it away, maybe someone will benefit from it. It happens so often, you write your problem down and then you have a wall of text and you solve it. But all the time and effort is wasted when you delete what you've written. Luckily there's the option to answer your own question when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it myself, however I'm getting a deprecation warning about `combineLatest`.
I found a [closed github issue about combineLatest being deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3618),
and also [a Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276165/combinelatest-deprecated-in-favor-of-static-combinelatest/56208571#56208571).

In any case this is my currently working solution

```
    this.community$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngDestroyed$),
      switchMap(community => {
        return combineLatest(this.store.select(selectProfileByID(community && community.owner_id)), this.container$);
      }),
    ).subscribe(([profile, container]) => {
      if ((profile) && (container)) {
        const claims = this.oAuthService.getIdentityClaims();
        if (claims) {
          // @ts-ignore
          const sub = claims.sub;
          if (sub === profile.subject_id) {
            this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({
              items: [
                {title: 'New Forum', route: ['/new/forum', container.id]}
              ]
            }));
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(setDrawerAdminNavigationItems({items: undefined}));
      }
    });
```

Comment: `combineLatest` is still supported, but not with multiple arguments, now `combineLatest` takes a single array as an argument. Just wrap your arguments in an array and you will get rid of the deprecation warning.

Comment: Thank you. The commit that does this: https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/6661c79