# Angular 7 wait for all subscriptions

Tags: angular, promise

I have a component that is currently set up like this:

```
export class CompareComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  criteria: Criteria[]
  products: Product[] = [];

  private organisationId: string

  private criteriaSubscription: Subscription
  private routeSubscription: Subscription
  private productSubscription: Subscription

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,

    private attributeMatchService: AttributeMatchService,
    private criteriaService: CriteriaService,
    private optionsService: OptionsService,
    private productService: ProductService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.organisationId = this.optionsService.get().organisation;
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      let category = paramMap.get('category');
      let gtins = paramMap.get('gtins').split('.');
      this.listCriteria(category);
      this.listProducts(category, gtins);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.criteriaSubscription) this.criteriaSubscription.unsubscribe();
    if (this.productSubscription) this.productSubscription.unsubscribe();
    if (this.routeSubscription) this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  close() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) return;
    window.history.back();
  }

  private listCriteria(category: string): void {
    this.criteriaSubscription = this.criteriaService.list(category, 'Attributes').subscribe(criteria => this.criteria = criteria);
  }

  private listProducts(category: string, gtins: string[]) {
    gtins.forEach(gtin => {
      this.productSubscription = this.productService.get(category, this.organisationId, parseInt(gtin)).subscribe(products => {
        this.products.push(products[0]);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see from the `listProducts` method, I get a list of products based on the **gtins** that have been passed as a parameter.
What I would like to do is wait for all the subscriptions to finish in `listProducts` and after they have done, to run some code.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this to combine the observables and wait for all, that's RxJs [How to 'wait' for two observables in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004144/how-to-wait-for-two-observables-in-rxjs)   You might also want to check out [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wait for all observables, use the `forkJoin` operator and then flatten the result to push it to your products array.

I'd also suggest to use the `takeUntil` operator as a cleanup helper for your subscriptions. See how it can be used in my example.

```
forkJoin(
      gtins.forEach(gtin => this.productService.get(category, this.organisationId, parseInt(gtin)))
    ).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
    ).subscribe(products => {
      this.products.push(...products.flat())
    });
```

And in your `onDestroy` hook

```
  onDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
```

And in your component, define `destroyed$` as

`destroyed$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();`

Comment: @ritaj beat me to it, but I'll leave this as a reference for a chained answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to do the pushing in `subscribe` rather than `map`? (AFAIK `map` is supposed to be side-effect free in functional reactive programming)

Comment: @meriton, very true, since we don't mutate the data there's no need for the map! Thanks! :)

Comment: @meriton Yes, it should be done inside `tap` or `subscribe`.

Comment: @DanielB Not only that, but you will map the result to the length of `this.products` array (since push returns array length), which will lose you the information for later stream chaining.

Comment: I get this error when using your code: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: on `gtins.forEach`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will need to use `forkJoin`.

It waits for all the Observables from the array to finish and then emits.

Do the individual observable operations inside `tap` of each of them.

```
private listProducts(category: string, gtins: string[]) {
    const products$: Observable<any>[] = [];

    gtins.forEach(gtin => {
        products$.push(this.productService.get(category, 1, parseInt(gtin))
                        .pipe(tap(product => {
                              this.products.push(products[0]);
        }));
    });

    forkJoin(products$).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('All subscriptions done');
    });
}
```