# Observable map property based on another observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Lets say i have an observable that emits employees.

`$employees`

I wish to manipulate a sub property of each employee based on an Observable. For the example lets say display name.

Currently im performing the task like this.

```js
const getDisplayName = (emp) => {}; //returns an observable

const mapFn = async (emp) => {
    emp.displayName = await getDisplayName(emp).toPromise();

    return emp;
}

$employees
    .pipe(mergeMap(mapFn));
```

I think my confusion is that, to my understanding, we have two streams. The root `$employees` and the `getDisplayName`. My understanding is with the various merge operators the root value would be *replaced* by the value of the secondary stream. Not merged with.

Is there a better way to do this where i don't need to convert to a promise but can also just map a property of the employee?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004144/how-to-wait-for-two-observables-in-rxjs?

Comment: I think what you have is correct.

Comment: I think you do not need to convert to Promise. This `$employees
    .pipe(mergeMap(getDisplayName))` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to do:

```
$employees
    .pipe(mergeMap(employees => {
      return forkJoin(employees.map(emp => getDisplayName(emp).pipe(
        map(displayName => ({...emp, ...{displayName}}))
      )))
    }));
```

if you really want a broken out mapFn:

```
const mapFn = employees => {
  return forkJoin(employees.map(emp => getDisplayName(emp).pipe(
    map(displayName => ({...emp, ...{displayName}}))
  )));
}

$employees
    .pipe(mergeMap(mapFn))
```

always advise against mixing rxjs and async / await. They're different methods of handling async operations and don't play nice.  `mergeMap` needs you to return an observable, `forkJoin` executes observables in parralel, so you join all your employees mapped into their `getName` functions and then map the name into the original employee and return it.

EDIT: the above is if `$eployees` is emitting an array of employees. if it's just a single employee, do:

```
const mapFn = emp => {
  return getDisplayName(emp).pipe(
    map(displayName => ({...e, ...{displayName}}))
  );
}
```

however, if it's emitting a single employee (or an array of employees) multiple times, it's important to understand the implications of using `mergeMap` vs `switchMap` vs `concatMap`. Let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const emp$ = from([1, 2, 3]);

function getName(emp: number): Observable<string> {
    return of(emp.toString());
}

const empNameTuple$ = emp$.pipe(mergeMap(emp => {
    return getName(emp).pipe(map(name => [emp, name]));
}))
```

Here I'm just returning a tuple of `[number, string]`, but you can map it however you wish.