# How to merge two observables in Angular/RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs-observables

In my service I have these methods:

```
  getMap(): any {
    return this.http.get(`someURL`);
  }

  getAssets(): any {
    return this.http.get(`someURL`);
  }
```

In my Component I use them like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getMap().subscribe(data => {
      this.map = data; // Returns ["map-1.svg", "map-0.svg"]
    });

    this.systemMapService.getAssets().subscribe(data =>  {
        this.assets = data; // Returns ["map-mapping-0.json", "map-mapping-1.json"]
    });
  }
```

In my template I want to use it like this:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="end">
  <div *ngFor="let item of assets; let i = index">
    <mat-tab label="{{i}}">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="map">
          <img id="img_equipment" [src]="apiUrl + '/path/to/svg/' + item">
          <a *ngFor="let link of map"
             title="{{ link.title }}"
             class="ink"
             [ngStyle]="{ left: link.left, top: link.top, width: link.width }">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
  </div>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I provided the return values of the calls as comments in die code.

For example, the file `map-0.svg` should use this JSON as a mapping `map-mapping-0.json`. The file `map-1.svg` then in turn this JSON file `map-mapping-1.json`.

..and do the arrays that the calls return have to be sorted for it to work? Because unfortunately they are currently being returned unsorted by the backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'wait' for two observables in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004144/how-to-wait-for-two-observables-in-rxjs)

Comment: *"do the arrays that the calls return have to be sorted for it to work"* - you tell us, do you want to match them by index (in which case yes) or can you do it by value (in which case not necessarily)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As mentioned in my description, the file map-0.svg should use the map-mapping-0.json. So the number at the end of the file name is crucial. Each .svg has a specific JSON file that it works with.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the rxjs operator `combineLatest`

Comment: I'm currently trying it with combineLatest but I can't adjust it for my use case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your template and description, it's not entirely clear what shape your data should take to make this easiest for you. Regardless, my instinct here would be to transform your data until it's easily consumed by your template and then use angular's async pipe.

```
// I'm making this an array of strings tuples, but it can 
// be whatever best serves your purpose
displayData = Observable<Array<[string, string]>>;
ngOnInit() {
 
  this.displayData = forkJoin({
    mapData: this.myService.getMap(),
    mapAssets: this.systemMapService.getAssets()
  }).pipe(
    map(({mapData, mapAssets}) => {
      const formattedData = mapData.map(mapInstance => {
          // You're going to have to define this function yourself
          // to effective organsize/sort/whatever your data. 
          const assetInstance = this.extractMapAsset(mapAssets, mapInstance);
          return [mapInstance, assetInstance];
      });
      return formattedData;
    })
  );
}

// In template
<div *ngFor='let tupleData of displayData | async'>
    The map is called {{tupleData[0]}} 
    and its assetJson is called {{tupleData[1]}}
</div>
```

This is a grossly simplified example, but it gets the basic structure. You join and format your data and then you display it in your view. In this example, it's just a tuple of strings, but it can be anything such that you view can have nested `ngFor*` calls displaying your data however you like.

Comment: It works with this approach :), thank you very much :).