# How can I wait for code/ subscription to finish before the function returns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to wait for the 2 subscription in my function to finish before it returns the value of 'this.getRows('employee')' . What would be the best way to do that? Maybe rxjs would help but I am bad with that. Thank you in advance

```
getEmployeesTable(): Table {
    this.backendService.getEmployeeSummaryTable().subscribe((employees) => {
      this.emloyeeSummary = employees;
    });
    this.backendService.getEmployeesTable().subscribe((employees) => {
      this.emloyees = employees;
    });
    setTimeout(() => (table = this.getRows('employee')), 1000); // this does not help

    return this.getRows('employee'); // this should only return after the 2 functions above 
                                     //finished 
  }
```

Comment: You might be able to use JavaScript promises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'wait' for two observables in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004144/how-to-wait-for-two-observables-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) will wait for two async operation to be completed

```
getEmployeesTable():Observable<Table>{
  
  return forkJoin({
    emloyeeSummary: this.backendService.getEmployeeSummaryTable(),
    employees: this.backendService.getEmployeesTable()
  }).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
     this.emloyeeSummary = res.emloyeeSummary;
     this.emloyees = res.employees;
    }),
    map(() => this.getRows('employee'))
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer with the `forkJoin`! Wondering about the `mergeMap` ... From the OP it didn't seem that the `getRows` returned an Observable? So maybe a `map` instead of the `mergeMap`?

Comment: I used it now with mergeMap because getRows does not return an observable and it works! Thank you!